# Problem with numberOfRowsInSection and dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a dictionary with a number of different bits of information all pulled from and xml feed. I now want to pull certain parts from the dictionary into areas to create my tableview.

so far creating the section headers was fine, but having a problem with the numberofrowsinsection part:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [[sections objectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"itemsCount"];
}
```

This gives the following error:  warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
Any help welcome on this very much newbie :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
return [[[sections objectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"itemsCount"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

objectForKey returns id -- which is not automatically convertible to NSInteger.  You need to cast this to the object type that you put in the dictionary and then convert that to NSInteger.